# Im trying to write the data in the list into an excel sheet,and the list is displayed as shown below.If i try list[0] i only get 22, how to get A too?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-science

so the when I just display list out its showed as:

```
A     22
WO     8
Name: 7, dtype: int64
```

and when I try list[0] it only prints the value 22.

how do I print the whole row like:

```
A   22
```

Also I'm trying to write this into an excel sheet. And im thinking to make a separate columns for A and WO with their corresponding values in the rows. Please let me know how to achieve that

Comment: That looks like a Pandas Series not a list. In which case try `s[[0]]` or perhaps `s[[0]].to_string()` instead to access where `s` is the Series (`s = pd.Series([22,8],index=['A', 'WO'], name=7)`)

Comment: Thanks so much!. It worked now. Also is there a way if we can read the index and sort it out? some of the lists start with A and some start with WO. Is there anything we can do about it???

Comment: Again. Not a list. If you're looking to slice a Series you can also do it by label.  For example if you always wanted `A` you can do `s[['A']]`. Or `s[['A', 'WO']]` if you always wanted A then WO  etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just started learning data science with no background whatsoever in coding.

Comment: That would imply that `Attendance` is an `int` not a `Series` or a `list`.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks for helping me out. I hope I get better at this!!

Comment: Well I didn't actually needed to do that anyway. It was just an extra step which I'm ignoring rn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step guide to writing lists to excel using pandas and printing the first row in the data frame (or all rows).

```py
import pandas as pd

list_1 = [0, 1, 2]
list_2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data_as_dictionary = {'Name':list_2, 'Value':list_1}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_as_dictionary)
# write df into excell  
df.to_excel('df_as_excel.xlsx', index=None)   
# print first row from the df 
print(df.loc[[0]])

# if you already have an excel and want to print the rows:
# 1. load in excel 
df2 = pd.read_excel('df_as_excel.xlsx', index_col=None)
# 2. print first row
print(df2.loc[[0]])
# 3. or if you want to print all rows in the df2
for row_number in range(len(df2)):
    print(df2.loc[[row_number]])
```